How to properly perform dynamic filtering using graphql-java?
Assume that using the schema below, both the teams query and the members collection (from the Team type) are bound to data served by different services using BatchLoaders. Also, let's assume that these services do not offer any mechanism and the GraphQL layer just stiches the two datasets.
type Query {
  teams(teamID:Int, namePrefix:String):[Team]
}

type Team {
  id: Int
  name: String!
  members: [User]
}

type User {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  teamId: Int!
  team: [Team]
}

The goal is to only retrieve teams and members that have the name equal to "John" when running the following query:
query {
    teams {
        id
        name
        members {
            id
            name
        }
    }
}

teams data:
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Team A",
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Team B",
    }
]

users data:
[
    {
        "id": 10,
        "name": "John",
        "teamId": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 20,
        "name": "Dave",
        "teamId": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 30,
        "name": "Bob",
        "teamId": 2
    }
]

expected result:
{
    "data": {
        "teams": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Team A",
                "members": [
                    {
                        "id": 10,
                        "name": "John"
                    },
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}

Question: Is there any standardized way to approach this problem? If not, what would be the most advisable approach?
I do understand that for that we can use runtime directives for that and currently I have evaluated two approaches using graphql-java:

Use a DirectiveWiring and wrap the datafetcher with code that performs the filtering;
Use a SimplePerformantInstrumentation and manipulate the result using the instrumentExecutionResult;

On option 1 there's a problem that the members collection would not yet be resolved given that the BatchLoader did not execute yet, and on option 2 the only way I found to perform the filtering was to revisit the data from the ExecutionResult and by doing a depth-first-search filter out unnecessary elements from the response.
